# Expand width of <hr> to width of page and change color of anchor tag

Tags: html, css

Here is example where I want to use `hr` which should expand entire width of page.
In below code I have not used `hr` even it shows `line` above the `alert` message. 
Hows does this line get drawn?

How can I expand it to entire width page?

Codepan demo : [Demo link](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/sfjpd)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The HTML5 Doc</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5">
  <meta name="author" content="Hadi">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="clearfix">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="menu col-md-8">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=""#>Top picks </a><span>beta</span></li>
        <li><a href=""#>Popular</a><span>beta</span></li>
          <li><a href=""#>Friends analysis </a></li>
      </ul>

      <p class="custom-alert">Article changes everyday! come back for more fun......<p>
    </div>
    </div><!--./row-->
</div><!--./container -->
</body>
</html>
```

More when I use `anchor` tag, color of text changes to blue. How can I make it `grey` for anchor tag also?

`<li><a href=""#>Top picks </a><span>beta</span></li>`

Comment: You have invalid HTML. `<a href=""#>` should be `<a href="#">`

Comment: @putvande I doubt he understand what you are saying since it's obvious that he copy/pasted this from someone else's code.

Comment: @AdonisK.: yes, I took this code some where. Is it out of SO policy? It accept it was typo, but it does not mean one code each line by himself. Dont know why downvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `<hr>` in your demo, it's a `ul` with a `border-bottom`. You can't add `width: 100%;` to your `ul` because it's already at full width of it's container that's because you are using bootstrap's grid system. Removing the `.col-md-8` will fix it.

To style your anchors, you should use:

```
a, a:visited {
    color: grey;
}
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/adonisk/pen/AufCv)

Answer (score 0):

for the `hr` try setting it to `width:100%` in your css. As far as the anchor tags you need to overwrite the default styles:

```
a{
    color: grey;
}
```

or you can add `class` names if you want them to be different colors

Comment: check my codepan demo. I have not used `hr` even it shows horizontal line. What draws that line?